# Timestamp on NFC

Tags: authentication, jwt, nfc

I have the following situation:
I would like to scan a NFC tag and open some URL. However I would like to implement my own Proof of Location, so that the URL hidden inside of NFC is only valid if you scan it in the place, where the NFC tag is placed.
The way I think about it, is that I would like to open URL in NFC and add a timestamp, when that action happened. This way I will be able to imitate a JWT and check if the user is valid. I would like the JWT to expire after some time. Also this solution prevents users from reentering the system from the outside, as the timestamp is on the NFC side instead of client side.
Is it possible to implement? Every answer is highly appreciated.

I did my own research on writing to the NFC, however I cant find anything about getting the timestamp.

Comment: NFC tag are powered by the (electric) field of a reader, so most times they are "off"". I don't know any NFC tags that are (battery) external powered so your tag can not provide an actual timestamp. Maybe a Bluetooth gadget is the better choice for your task.

Comment: While there are no off the self Tag that I know off that offer maintain power themselves, but there are plenty of NFC chips that you can design with a microcontroller or other general computing device and a battery. But really to make any sense of what you are trying to do, you need to specify  more detail about the hardware evironment you expect this system to run on.